# Grep for string begining and ending with underscores

Tags: linux, shell, grep, command-line-interface

I need to use grep from the command line to match a string with the following format

```
_ADFADF_ASFDSAFD_AFDSADF_
```

Should not match on

```
ASDFASDF_ASFDASDF_AFSDASFD
_ASDFASDF_ASDFASDF_ASDFAS
ASDFASD_ASDFSADF_ASFDASD_
```

Match should be only for a string begining and ending with an underscore and underscores may be in the middle of the string. String may be located in middle of line for instance....

```
SetODBCServerOverride.port=_CLIENT_ODBC_TUNNEL_PORT_
```

In the following example, I need to match _THIS_MATCHES_RIGHT_HERE_ and not match THIS_DOES_NOT_MATCH

Blah Blah Blah "**_THIS_MATCHES_RIGHT_HERE_**" so it's good
Yadda Yadda THIS_DOES_NOT_MATCH and it isn't good. _THIS_ALSO_DOES_NOT_MATCH so...

Comment: Your examples now include `=_FOO_BAR_` and `"_FOO_BAR_` but not `T_FOO_BAR_`. I.e. you count underscores after `=` and `"` but not after `T`. Can you list/describe the characters you want to allow before the first `_`? How about `__FOO_`, `/_FOO_`, `-_FOO_`, `3_FOO_`, `#_FOO_`, `@_FOO_`?

Comment: all non alphanumeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `^` and `$` to specify the beginning and end of a line respectively:

```
$ grep '^_.*_$' file.txt
```

**EDIT:**

Now that the requirement have been clarified - you can use the special `\<` and `\>` characters to specify the beginning and end of a word, respectively, and `\S` to specify non-whitespace characters (so you don't match strings like `_ABC   DEF_`:

```
$ grep '\<_\S*_\>' file.txt
```

Comment: I should add that this is not always on begining of line.

Comment: @Brian Then why shouldn't `ASDFASDF_ASFDASDF_AFSDASFD` match? It contains `_ASFDASDF_` in the middle, which has the format you want

Comment: I need it to start with underscore and end with underscore

Comment: `_ASFDASDF_` starts with underscore and ends with underscore

Comment: @Brian I think I understand the requirement now. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -E "([^a-zA-Z0-9]|^)_[A-Za-z0-9_]*_([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)" filename
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
grep ^_ | grep _$
```

or you can use REGEX

```
grep -E "^_[A-Z_]+_$"
```

Comment: This matches strings that do not start with underscore but have an underscore such as ASDFASD_ASDFAS_ASDFASD_

Comment: @Brian I have tested it, it works on my machine but, there are some things that I have changed for grep in past so my previous answer would work, however it did not work on my VM, which tells me that it wont work on many other systems.